# How do I correct date values in a SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm

I am trying to fix an order problem for a column in a SQL table. The column has dates but with the type `varchar`, and they are in this format: `mm/dd/yy`. I did not make it this way, the person behind me did and left.

How do I change all the entries to be the format `yyyy/mm/dd`? Once I put them in this format I will make a new column of type `date` and I will convert all the values and put them in there. My question is, which command do I use to change these dates? They're all in the 2000s so I can just add "20" to all the year parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this, using [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

- Add a `date` column (called `newdate` for example)
- Execute this:

  `UPDATE table SET newdate = STR_TO_DATE(olddate, '%m/%d/%y');`
- Test it
- Drop the old column and optionally rename the new one to suit.

Make sure you use `%y` and not `%Y`: The lower-cased version works with 2-digit years.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with string manipulations:

```
update t
    set col = concat('20', right(col, 2), '/', left(col, 5))
    where col like '%/%/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
STR_TO_DATE(MyDateCol, '%m/%d/%y')
```